# Pull nodes from XML with perl and LibXML and parse the results

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, libxml2

I have an problem I could sure use some help with.  First, be gentle.  I am new to both perl and LibXML.

I have been parsing a document and placing elements into an array that is then written to a spreadsheet column. During testing it was discovered that some nodes have more than one child node of the same name.  I need to combine the text from each of these child nodes into one element of the array.

The (very simplified) format of the xml is:

```
<Group>
<title>
<description>
<reference>
<fixtext>
<check>
    <check-content> "Some text I want to pull"
```

But occasionally it is like this:

```
<Group>
<title>
<description>
<reference>
<fixtext>
<check>
    <check-content> "Some text I want to pull"
    <check-content> "Some more text I want to pull and join to the first"
```

I can pull everything below `<check>`, but cannot pull the `<check-content>` from that variable.

What I have been doing is:

```
my @Check_Content;
my $Check_Content;
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new() or die $!;
my $doc1 = $parser->parse_file($filename1);
my $xc1 = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($doc1->documentElement() );
$xc1->registerNs(x => 'http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.1');

for my $Check ( $xc1->findnodes('//x:Group/x:Rule/x:check') ) { 

    print "This is Check $Check\n";

    my $result_string;

     for my $Check_Content ( $Check->findvalue('check-content') ) { 

     print "This is Check Content $Check_Content\n";

     $result_string .= $Check_Content->to_literal;
     }

 push (@Check_Content, $result_string);
 }
```

The first print statement proves that everything below `<check>` is being pulled. However the second print statement is always empty. It's as if it is no longer in XML format and it cannot pull the node.

I have used every variable of ('check-content') I could think of, ie

- `('/check-content')`
- `('//check-content')`
- `('/x:check-content')`
- `('//check-content')`
- `('//x:check-content')`

There could be one I missed, but I don't think so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A few points to start with, to keep in mind when posting future questions:

- You did not provide an easily-usable test case. In particular:

  - Your XML document was not complete and well-formed.
  - The XPath queries you gave did not even match the XML fragment that you provided.
  - You left off the namespace markup in your XML.
- You did not read the error messages that perl gave you.

So here is a valid XML document for your use case:

```
<x:Group xmlns:x="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.1">
  <x:title>
    <x:description>
      <x:reference>
        <x:fixtext>
          <x:check>
            <x:check-content> "Some text I want to pull"</x:check-content>
            <x:check-content> "Some more text I want to pull and join to the first"</x:check-content>
          </x:check>
        </x:fixtext>
      </x:reference>
    </x:description>
  </x:title>
</x:Group>
```

And here is a (nearly-complete, except for the initial parsing code at the top) script to process your XML:

```
my @Check_Content;
my $Check_Content;
my $xc1 = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($doc1->documentElement() );
$xc1->registerNs(x => 'http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.1');

for my $Check ( $xc1->findnodes('//x:Group//x:check') ) {
  print "This is Check $Check\n";
  my $result_string;
  for my $Check_Content ( $Check->findvalue('x:check-content') ) {
    print "This is Check Content $Check_Content\n";
    $result_string .= $Check_Content->to_literal;
  }

  push (@Check_Content, $result_string);
}
```

And when I run this script over this XML, I get this output:

```
This is Check <x:check>
                <x:check-content> "Some text I want to pull"</x:check-content>
                <x:check-content> "Some more text I want to pull and join to the first"</x:check-content>
              </x:check>
This is Check Content  "Some text I want to pull" "Some more text I want to pull and join to the first"
Can't locate object method "to_literal" via package " "Some text I want to pull" "Some more text I want to pull and join to the first"" (perhaps you forgot to load " "Some text I want to pull" "Some more text I want to pull and join to the first""?) at ./hm.pl line 27, <DATA> line 15.
```

So two issues pop out immediately:

- Both nodes are being extracted as a single result
- `findcontent()` returns a string; you can't call `to_literal()` on it.

So to fix this:

- Change your `findcontent()` call to a `findnodes()` call.
- Bob's your uncle.

Good luck!